# Dell Inspiron 5558 the Wi-Fi and Lan speed on it are very slow and gets normal with a static IP only

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, dd-wrt, dell-inspiron

For more than a week now I had some issues with my Wi-Fi connection speed. I used to get more than 30mbps, but since this issue it gave me less than 10Mbps. My drivers and BIOS are updated to the latest, I tried lots of things recommended on the web, but nothing worked! Till today I changed the dynamic IP to Static and the speed just turned to normal as it was!!
Did anyone have this issue, and have a fix for it? And Can anyone explain why this is happening?

> My Router is  Linksys E1200 v2, that runs the latest DD-WRT for
>   it. My System is Windows 10, and the WNIC is Intel(R) Dual Band
>   Wireless-AC 3160

Comment: Changing the IP protocol as you did would have essentially done a TCP/IP reset and that is what very likely fixed the speed issue

Comment: @John few days ago I made a network reset and that didn't work.

Comment: If DHCP remains slow and Static remains fast, and you did a TCP/IP reset already, then it now may be a router problem. Can you test the router with a different machine?

Comment: @John I did, my mobile and other devices work great, I think its this laptop problem. its the same even with different routers, and just now I tested the speed and it got less again!!!!

Comment: At this point try a USB wireless card and see if the different card works better

Comment: @John I will try that tomorrow and will tell you if anything changed.. thank you for your time John

Comment: Wi-Fi speeds are very dependent on the Wi-Fi capabilities of your AP and client hardware. Please edit your question to provide the exact make and model of your AP and client WNIC. For example, if you're running DD-WRT on the original Linksys WRT54G it was originally developed for, then 10Mbps is decent and 30Mbps is spectacular, because all it can do is 802.11g and those speeds are all one could expect of 802.11g.

Comment: @John you are right about the network reset, I think the normal reset didn't do it correctly but when I changed the IP everything gone to normal just needed time for adjustment with the router

Comment: @Spiff I edited my question above, but the problem was not just on wifi only but on the Lan side to.

Comment: So has speed returned to normal?

Comment: @John yes it did

Comment: So if I post my first comment will you mark it as an answer?

Comment: @John yes I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the IP protocol as you did would have essentially done a TCP/IP reset and that is what very likely fixed the speed issue.